# Вводится число от 20 до 99. Написать программу, выводящую название этого числа (20 - двадцать и т.д.). надо написать код на питоне

Tags: python

я написала код, но мне выдает, что код проходит не все тесты. я пыталась найти ошибку, но попробовав все числа в данном диапазоне так и не нашла ее. вот код:

```
    a=int(input())
    if a//10==2:
        print("Двадцать",end=" ")
    if a//10==3:
        print("Тридцать",end=" ")
    if a//10==4:
        print("Сорок",end=" ")
    if a//10==5:
        print("Пятьдесят",end=" ")
    if a//10==6:
        print("Шестьдесят",end=" ")
    if a//10==7:
        print("Семьдесят",end=" ")
    if a//10==8:
        print("Восемьдесят",end=" ")
    if a//10==9:
        print("Девяносто",end=" ")
    if a%10==1:
        print("один",end=" ")
    if a%10==2:
        print("два",end=" ")
    if a%10==3:
        print("три",end=" ")
    if a%10==4:
        print("четыре",end=" ")
    if a%10==5:
        print("пять",end=" ")
    if a%10==6:
        print("шесть",end=" ")
    if a%10==7:
        print("семь",end=" ")
    if a%10==8:
        print("восемь",end=" ")
    if a%10==9:
        print("девять",end=" ")
```

Comment: Недостаточно информации. Какой имено тест не проходит? Возможно лишний `end=" "` в единицах?

Comment: Зачем вам параметр end в единицах? И если проблема действительно в пробеле в конце строки, то и на все круглые десятки (20,30 итд) тест тоже не пройдёт.

Comment: Совсем недавно где-то дубликат был. Надо поискать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Cпособ преобразовать числовые слова в целые числа Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1547543/c%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-python)

Answer (score 3):

Однострочник

```
print(f'''{" ".join((('', '', 'двадцать', 'тридцать', 'сорок', 'пятьдесят', 'шестьдесят', 'семьдесят', 'восемьдесят', 'девяносто'), ('', 'один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять'))[i][j] for i, j in enumerate(divmod(int(input()), 10)))}'''.strip().capitalize())
```

Answer (score 2):

Добрые люди сделали [библиотеку](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/)

```
from num2words import num2words
print(num2words(123456789, lang='ru')) # сто двадцать три миллиона четыреста пятьдесят шесть тысяч семьсот восемьдесят девять
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = int(input())

tens = a // 10
units = a % 10

tens_words = {
    2: "Двадцать",
    3: "Тридцать",
    4: "Сорок",
    5: "Пятьдесят",
    6: "Шестьдесят",
    7: "Семьдесят",
    8: "Восемьдесят",
    9: "Девяносто"
}

units_words = {
    1: "один",
    2: "два",
    3: "три",
    4: "четыре",
    5: "пять",
    6: "шесть",
    7: "семь",
    8: "восемь",
    9: "девять"
}

if tens in tens_words:
    print(tens_words[tens], end=" ")

if units in units_words:
    print(units_words[units], end=" ")
```

На крайний случай, объедините вывод в один print без end

Comment: `tens = a // 10` и `units = a %` 10 можно заменить одним `divmod`